# jQuery image gallery slider Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have a completed webpage with an image slider implemented. In my local machine, it works fine, but when I uploaded it on the server, the right arrow image for the slider does not show up. In firebug, the image fails to load, even though going to the url of the image,  , it does show up.

Scrolling the page a little lower, we can find the slider under the gallery heading. You can see that the right arrow is missing, even though if you click on the invisible spot of the arrow, it still functions the slider.

I tried updating the image/css but that didn't work out.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is wrong.

In you page is 
http://www.domainandseo.com/portfolio/villa/images/RightArrow-normal.png

And the right one is 
http://www.domainandseo.com/portfolio/villa/images/rightArrow-normal.png

change R to r.

Comment: oh, that was a silly mistake of mine. I just changed it and uploaded the updated css. But for some reason i still cannot see the image. Maybe its because cache or something. Does it work for you now?

Comment: I opened you page again and the url is still with R.

Edit: it's ok now.